# How to extract 8 letters UPPERCASE string from file in bash script

Tags: bash, find, extract

I'd like to extract from 1000 files some string based on these conditions:
extract all string which is 8 letters long and all UPPERCASE.
AND
extract all string which beginning with 3 UPPERCASE letters followed by numbers. like ABC1234567 or ABC12345
ABC is fix letters.

Comment: It can be done using regular expression but we want to see what you have done so far. Try simple tasks with regex and then work on your files.

Comment: I have no coding skills, so I did not write any code yet.

Comment: Well the best way to get some to is practise!

Comment: Ok, I will learn regexp now, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -aoE -e '[A-Z]{8}' -e 'ABC[0-9]+' file
```

Comment: Wow! That was the correct answer! Many thanks Cyrus! Also to everyone!